# How to start a process when tomcat is full started?

Tags: spring, process, block, startup

I am working on an application, using Spring and Camel,
I need to treat bundles of messages, not message ONE by ONE.
So I create a folder for each bundle, and I start process when the bundle is complete.
But when we shut the server (delivery for instance), we shut Camel too, so I need to treat each bundle interrupted when tomcart is OK...
The problem is, during process, the server calls itself (to force autocommits), and the process is very long.
So, I tried

- ContextStartedEvent and ContextRefreshEvent => tomcat doesn't start because more than 400 seconds and call itself doesn't work (it seems that tomcat is not properly startup in this step, webservices are OFF)
- ContextStartedEvent and ContextRefreshEvent with new Thread( ...) in order not to block => same
- ServletContextListener => same result
- HttpServlet => same result

Is there a way to start a process when tomcat is full started without blocking or slow startup ?

Thanks, and sorry for my english :(